# Comments in python don’t work after sublime upgrade to 3103

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I just upgraded to Sublime 3103, and now the comment shortcut `command+/` does not work. This is weird because it doesn't work only in Python. For all other programming languages, it works just fine.

I tried setting up a custom keybinding for comments, and again the same problem. Works everywhere else, except in python.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You should report this, along with much more information about your environment and settings, to the maintainers; this isn't a question SO can help you with.

Comment: Have you tried checking your python specific settings in `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific`? Also, what packages do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also cannot reproduce this, but here is a way to fix it. Go to **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** to open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager. Create a new folder named `Python`, and inside that new folder create an empty file named `Comments.tmPreferences` (capitalization is important). Next, open the new file in Sublime with XML syntax highlighting and add the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>6550FEAD-D547-44E4-84F7-7D421D6078B0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save the file, and it should take effect immediately.

---

This works by explicitly telling Sublime to use a certain pattern for comments. The `.tmPreferences` extension came from [TextMate](http://macromates.com), a pretty good editor for OS X that Jon Skinner used as one of his inspirations (along with `vi`) when writing Sublime. (BTW, if you're on OS X, check out TextMate 2 - it's open-source, and has a lot of neat features. A much smaller plugin community, though...)

As you can see, the file is XML-based, and defines a `shellVariable` named `TM_COMMENT_START` (again, the `TM` is from TextMate) which is used internally to demarcate a single-line comment. Depending on the `scope` value, a `Comments.tmPreferences` file can be used for any language you wish. If your programming language also has a block comment construct, as well as a single-line comment, you can define that with `TM_COMMENT_START_2` and `TM_COMMENT_END_2` like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>"""</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>"""</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>6550FEAD-D547-44E4-84F7-7D421D6078B0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here, we're still in Python, but we're using triple quotes to define a block comment or docstring. Simply highlight the region you want to surround with triple quotes and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> on Windows/Linux).